# Access Membership and Role tables from asp using PHP

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I am developing a PHP application which uses the userdata of a .NET application. I found out that I need to use Membership and Role tables but I have no idea how to call the getUser() function from . NET application thru the use of a php script. How can I access the membership and role tables if I am using PHP??

I have been looking in google for ways that I could use to validate user logins from PHP to ASP, but I cannot seem to find any. Are there ways that I could just call the Membership.ValidateUser() or any other function of Membership and Role tables using php?

```
<?php

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

// I clearly have no idea what to do here since I'm used to using MySQL connections.
?>
```

Comment: The easiest way will be create a rest/webservice proxy on the asp.net side which will wrap the ValidateUser function. Then call this url from PHP.

Comment: @MajoB I've looked into NUSOAP, would this be a viable solution? But quite frankly your suggestion seems to be easier in my opinion.

Comment: I haven't any experience with NUSOAP.